# C# wrapper to C++ function - Run once, works okay. Run twice, program hangs

Tags: c#, c++, interop, language-interoperability

So I am working with a c# wrapper to a C++ library, and trying to add another function. I have created the function declaration in C# and it is working. But it only works once. When I try to run it the second time, the program hangs.

The interop definitions and declarations are at https://github.com/joshglenn/interception-cs/blob/master/kchordr/Program.cs

the code I am running is here: https://github.com/joshglenn/interception-cs/blob/master/kchordr/InterceptionDemoForm.cs

The function that runs fine the first time but hangs on the second launch is GetHardwareID().

My question is, how can I troubleshoot this? Does this appear to be a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the error code from the WinAPI call use the **Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()**;
Also remember to decorate your call with "Set Last Error = true";

Here is an example i have for calling a popup on a taskbar icon :

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool Shell_NotifyIcon(uint dwMessage, [In] ref NotifyIconData pnid);
```

usage:

```
//call your code like you usually call the method
bool callResult = Caller.Shell_NotifyIcon((uint)NotifyIconMessage.NIM_ADD, ref n);

//afther that call the GetLastError to get the error code
int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

google the error code and see what it means

Comment: Thanks for that. That will come in handy. It turns out my error was being caused by improper use of the underlying API. My function declarations were correct. Thanks again!

Comment: It turns out my function declarations were okay. I was using the underlying API incorrectly. I am marking yours as the answer as this should help others troubleshoot similar issues.